# Qt: display window content on slow startup

Tags: c++, qt, redraw

It feels like this question has been asked about a hundred times before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052907/qt-repaint-redraw-update-do-something)) but I haven't found a working solution yet..

I have a Qt5 program (Linux) which takes some time (about 2sec) for initialization. I don't want to spawn a thread (for several reasons) and before initialization is done the program is not usable anyway.

Currently the program starts and it shows a black window, until initialization is done.

I'd like to have the window content be drawn as soon as possible and **queue** a method which does the rest which gets executed right after the main window has been drawn.

This is what I tried:

```
class my_window : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
    explicit my_window(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {

        initializeUI();

        /// UI is ready and should be drawn. initializeRest() should 
        /// be queued 

        /// tried to repaint() or update() the MainWindow and to 'force'
        /// processing outstanding events - with no effect
        update();
        repaint();
        QApplication::processEvents();

        /// don't call - just queue 
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "initializeRest", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }

    void initializeRest() {
        // do stuff which takes a while
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}
```

But the main window stayes black until `initializeRest()` has been executed.

How can I tell Qt to execute `initializeRest()` *right after* the window has been constructed?

I can think of starting a timer (bad, introduces extra latency) or an event handler which reacts on some kind of "WindowDrawn" event (bad, complicated).

What's the Qt-way to do this?

**Update**:

I've also tried to put the `initializeRest()` method into the `main()` function like suggested by Murphy:

```
my_window::my_window(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    initializeUI();
}

int main(int a_argsc, char *a_argsv[]) {
    QApplication l_application(a_argsc, a_argsv);
    my_window mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    QApplication::processEvents();
    mainWindow.initializeRest();
    return l_application.exec();
}
```

With same results: Waiting for a couple of seconds inside `initializeRest()` makes show up the initially black main window and be drawn right after `initializeRest()` returned (which seems to be logical to me because the event loop has not been started yet..)

Comment: I would suggest having a splash before showing the main window that can give you some time while loading , is that appropriate for you?

Comment: Well - that might be an option and I would be more what users expect. Currently it would feel a bit like giving up :). I'd really like to know what I should do to invoke this function after showing the UI.

Comment: *before initialization is done the program is not usable anyway.* , so why would you show a window that is not usable for some seconds? I think a splash screen is much more convenient for such a situation. . .

Comment: You're right - that's the way I will do it and that's why I've upvoted your comment. I just want to know how to convince Qt to just draw a window and run a method *afterwards*.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: This suggestion doesn't solve the issue; it's left here for completeness.

You can split the startup into smaller steps in `main()`:

1. Create the `QApplication` instance.
2. Instantiate the main window (I'll call the variable `mainWindow` here). You can safely remove all that repaint-workaround stuff after `initializeUI();` from the constructor of your code example.
3. Call `mainWindow.show()` to enforce showing the main window, followed by a call to `QApplication::processEvents()` to enforce the paint events being handled.
4. Do all the other initialization stuff of your application.
5. Start the event loop as usual by calling `QApplication::exec()`.

Be aware that with complex applications/main window implementations it can get quite hairy to do everything in the right order; a `QSplashScreen` would surely be the less tedious solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this is just calling the `initializeRest()` method from another function. I tried it without success. When I put a brakepoint at the beginning of `initializeRest()` I can still see a black window which hasn't been drawn yet.

Comment: @frans No, it isn't, because you don't call `mainWindow.show()` anywhere. What exactly did you try? Please add it to your question.

Comment: I've updated my post - maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: @frans No, you didn't; that's how it works here for a main window derived from `QDialog` in Qt4 - perhaps there's a difference in handling `QMainWindow` instances when setting it to visible prior to running the event loop? Sorry I can't help you here.

Comment: Maybe behavior changed from Qt4 to Qt5. I can't remember having trouble like this..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think the problem is based not on `show()` function. Try to run the next [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0pmN.png).

If add a button to boxLayout the application starts fast. But if I try `setGeometry()` the application takes a long time to start.

Comment: Please include your code as **text** (properly formatted as a code block) - not as a linked image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).